# Are language, context and truth connected?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

I have been thinking about the following problem for years and can't seem to resolve it. I'm looking for more information on the subject and would really appreciate some further reading on the following subject:

*Hypothesis*: Observations lift reality into the realm of the "Observed reality"; just like mathematics lifts reality into the "logical reality" or "computed reality". In this reality can be seen as "state" and observations, mathematics and even language can be seen as "[monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory))".

By reducing science to a Category of axioms (the objects) and changes (the morphisms), how can we describe "Observations", "Mathematics" and even "Languages" in terms of this Category?

My question is specifically: Is there research being done in this field and are there books/papers I can read on the subject? Thank you in advance for any help/thoughts/opinions/links.

Comment: For a start, you'd need to mathematically define, what the structure of an "axiom" object is, such that morphisms in its category preserve that structure; and of course, you'd need to demonstrate that the morphisms compose appropriately.

Comment: Another thing is, in my experience, 'axioms' in mathematics are typically defined as something *fundamental*, that is, something that can't be derived from other things. But the existence of a morphism *to* a supposed "axiom object" implies that object can in fact be derived, which would then make it no longer fundamental.

Comment: Finally, could you elaborate in what way you think that e.g. observations can be seen as monads in the category-theoretic sense, as distinct from the Leibnizian sense?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I can try and answer the questions but keep in mind that I'm not *that* well versed in CR. I think that within an axiomatic categorical system you can always have derived object. For example, $1$ can be the "axiom" in this case and $+$ a morphism. A "Logical" category would be the natural numbers, "lifting" my axiom and morphism.

Comment: Now an "Observational" category would be applying an observation, something done with senses, to an axiom. Imagine being able to lift axiom, for example laws of nature, into "Logical" categories like the category of atoms and again lift this into a "Logical" category of molecules. When I finally observe a rock falling I can create a morphism from a "Logical" category to an "Observational" category by only applying a sense (sight, etc) to the state of my logical system. This sense should have no impact on the underlying structures and can by definition be composed.

Comment: The same goes for "Language", where talking about, or writing about an object lifts our state. Potentially removing the philosophical problems we might have with "describing" a test to falsify a theory through language. Or at the least gain a new perspective on what "observations" are...

Comment: (I apologise for the horrible spelling and errors, can only edit a comment for 5 minutes after posting...)

Comment: Well, firstly, keep in mind that words like ['axiom'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom) and ['lifting'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(mathematics)) have established and specific meanings in mathematics and CT, so i would recommend avoiding using them unless you're sure you're using them according to those common definitions. Otherwise it might make it unnecessarily difficult to communicate your ideas to the people who might otherwise be possibly able to help you. :-)

Comment: Secondly, following on from that, in CT, in the sense you call "1" an 'axiom', you're simply describing an 'object' in a certain category (for example, the categories 'Set' or 'FinSet').

Comment: More generally, what you're describing here in the comments seems to be an attempt to treat CT as a general philosophical system, rather than as a mathematical system, with very specific mathematical definitions/meanings, which potentially has some philophical implications in certain areas (e.g. logics).

Comment: You talk about "a morphism from a 'Logical' category to an 'Observational' category by only applying a sense". A morphism between categories is called a ['functor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). So what you would need to do is *mathematically*, within the rules of CT, define the category 'Logic[al]', the category 'Observation', and how 'sense' is a functor between those two categories in the CT sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible references:

- Ralf Krömer, [Tool and Object: A History and Philosophy of Category Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=41bHxtHxjUAC&printsec=frontcover) (2007);
- Jean-Pierre Marquis, [From a Geometrical Point of View: A Study of the History and Philosophy of Category Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=bvy0aANuhPYC&printsec=frontcover) (2009).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to mark this as answered

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read [the 'Philosophical Significance' section of the SEP's entry on 'Category Theory'](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/#3)?